# Не будет ли нарушением правил google использование In-app Billing для реализации возможности доната в своем android приложении?

Tags: android

Не будет ли нарушением правил google использование In-app Billing для реализации возможности доната в своем android приложении? Не нашел информации про это в документации.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под донатом? Куда будут перечисляться деньги?

Comment: Тоесть функция поддержать разработчика. Пользователь нажимает "поддержать разработчика" после чего появляется набор карточек с фиксированными сумамы  и пользователь выбирает какую сумму  он готов пожертвовать. Деньги перечисляться в сервисы google. In-app billing от google позволяет реализовать встроенные покупки в android приложении, но в данном случае пользователь не получает никакой цифровой товар потому возникает вопрос не запрещено ли это google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, не будет. Если деньги пойдут через гугл, платить в приложении можно практически за что угодно законное. Понятно, что вам нужно предупредить пользователя, что "дополнительный контент он не получит".

И, если у вас возник такой вопрос, я бы в качестве доп безопасности сделал маленький `TextView`,где-нибудь в уголку, "пользователь задонатил". Если вдруг возникнет вопрос - всегда можно сказать "я продаю показ текста" :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы очень помогли.